# Better approach to use script inside nested directory PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, pythonpath

Sorry for asking my own question 2nd time, but i am totally stuck in `import file` in python.

I have a directory structure below:

```
|--test/foo.py
|--library  #This is my PYTHONPATH
|--|--script1.py
|--|--library_1
|--|--|--script2.py
|--|--library_2
|--|--library_3
```

I am accessing `library/library_1/script2.py` from `test/foo.py`.

Here i am confused about what is the better approach. Generally all library folders or utility functions should be added to `pythonpath`.

This is a folder structure i am maintaining to differentiate utility functions and test scripts.

I tried putting `__init__.py` in library and library1 & then imported like `from library1 import script2`, but getting error as `No module named script`.

I have tried appending that path to system path as well.

Working: if i add another `pythonpath` like `path/to/library/libray_1/`. So should i do this for all folders which are inside `library` folder to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

```
|--test/foo.py
|--library  #This is my PYTHONPATH
|--__init__.py
|--|--script1.py
|--|--library_1
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--|--script2.py
|--|--library_2
|--|--|--__init__.py
|--|--library_3
|--|--|--__init__.py
```

And inside the first `__init__.py` below library you need to do:

```
import library1
import library2
import script
```

Then, if `library` is your python path, you can do this within `test/foo.py` with no errors:

```
import library
library.library1.bar()
library.script.foo()
```